# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (420,) and (19,)

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.7

estava realizando este codigo y al querer correrlo me sale el error de: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (420,) and (19,), alguna sugerencia para corregirlo.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

velocidad_de_stall = 21.26
velocidad_maxima = 60
peso = 140


n_max = round((2.1+(24000/(peso+10000))),2)
print(n_max)
n_max_margen = 1.5*n_max
print(n_max_margen)
n_min = round(-.4*(n_max),2)
print(n_min)
n_min_margen = 1.5*n_min
print(n_min_margen)
velocidad_maxima_stall = 140*1.5

x = list(np.arange(0,velocidad_maxima_stall,0.5))
y = list(np.arange(n_min_margen,n_max_margen,0.5))
# x1 = velocidad_de_stall* np.sqrt(x)


plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Velocidad (m/s)')
plt.ylabel('Load Factor')
plt.title('V-n')
plt.show()
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos problemas

1. Tienes que pasarle a matplotlib arrays, no listas. Para ello simplemente queda la parte de tú código así:

```
x = np.arange(0,velocidad_maxima_stall,0.5))
y = np.arange(n_min_margen,n_max_margen,0.5))
```

2. El vector `x` y el vector `y` **tienen que tener el mismo tamaño**. Tú vector `x` tiene 420 datos, mientras que el `y` tiene 19. Para representar un punto en un gráfico, siempre necesitas saber para cada punto cual es su valor en el eje de abscisas y cual es su valor en el eje de ordenadas.